# How to build CDATA values in xml2js for node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to parse a xml file and then change CDATA value of some nodes using xml2js. And then write the new xml document into that file. I've tried everything, but still not getting anywhere. I tried using string "" and "cdata" option in builder class. But it doesn't work. It always writes the text node as undefined i.e. [![CDATA[undefined]]

```
fs.readFile(xmlFileUrl, function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
        //Change a node value to something .... and then build it
        var xml = builder.buildObject(result);
        fs.writeFile(xmlFileUrl), xml, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This code is syntactically invalid, it can't possibly work.

Comment: I've just given the brief version. I use object notation and change some properties of "result"  object and then built it using "builder" class.

Comment: That's not the point. Your sample code has a syntax error. Provide a sample that *actually runs* and shows the issue, so that others can reproduce it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve